# C++ DLL which uses gstreamer only runs on W10 machine where it was created but not on others

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, windows-10

Currently I'm writing a driver to provide a camera stream to a calibration software. System is Windows 10 32bit and language is C++. I used the provided project template from the calibration software supplier in VS 2017 Community. The template was made for VS2015 and I didn't upgrade to VS2017.

In a first step I used libjpeg to access the mjpeg stream and that worked fine - also on different machines. Now I want use the gstreamer to be able to also work with the H.264 stream the camera can provide.

So I installed the current x86 gstreamer runtime and development packages and wrote and built the DLL. I can run the test application from the supplier, load the DLL and it works fine on the PC where I compiled the DLL. I can see the camera stream in every format the camera supports.

But when I copy the test application and the DLL to another PC, the test application can't load the DLL. It says that any other DLL is missing, but doesn't tell me which one.

Then, I have set up another PC and compiled the DLL there. Again the test application can load the DLL and it works without a problem on that 2nd PC.

But the DLL from the 1st PC doesn't work on the 2nd PC and vice-versa. As each DLL works on the PC where it was created I assume that all dependencies are fulfilled. Analysing the DLL with [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) shows no missing dependencies.

So why doesn't it run on another PC?

Comment: Assuming that the computer that can run the program is A and the other is B, please provide the difference between A and B, such as the operating system, VS version, etc. Also did you link the DLL on B following the steps on this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170#to-add-the-dll-header-to-your-include-path)?

Comment: I did not fully follow the guide as the supplier offers a VS plugin which allows to start a new project. So I started with this. But the problem didn't appear when I used libjpeg and the resulting DLL ran on A and B. But in conjunction with gstreamer it doesn't work.

Comment: I have no exposure to gstreamer, have you ever used gstreamer in vs? Is it compatible with vs?

Comment: No, I didn't. According to gstreamer doc it is compatible.